# How to display ArrayList data in tabular format in android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a problem in display data in to respective fields.

I have like this data from database in arraylist.

```
 ArrayList<String> ar= new ArrayList<String>;
```

ar data is:-> `[2, India#1, USA#3, Australia#1, Germany#2];`

How to get above data like this arraylist:

```
 Country ArrayList: India,USA,Australai, Gernamy
 valucheck arraylist: 1,3,1,2
```

Here first element is id and others ara values. Like India- EditText field and integer(1,2,3) is radiobutton.

```
 India         1(checked first radio button)
 India         3(checked third radio button)
 Australia     1(Checked first radio button)
 Germany       2(Checked second radio button)
```

I have been trying lots of time, but could get proper solution, so please update some tricks for display those data
 I want to display like this data in to tabular form

**What i did,**

```
 List<EditText> listET = new ArrayList<EditText>();
 ArrayList<String> first= new ArrayList<String>();
if(edittextfield){
first.add("India");first.add("USA");first.add("Australia");first.add("Germany");

      EditText et_text_input = new EditText(getContext());
         for(int p=0;p<listET.size()+1;p++){
                    et_text_input.setText(first.get(p));
                    listET.add(et_text_input);
                    ll.addView(et_text_input);
                    }
  }else if(radiobuttonfield){
 what to do in radiobutton.
 }
```

Here If i put data in list of `first` in static, then works fine, but how to put about `ar` list data into first list ..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)-class.

Answer (score 0):

Look into ArrayAdapter (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) which allows you to  display the data in a ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean output to console, you could step through the list and display it's items with tab separation

```
//As an example of usage, not a solution using your structures
for (MyObject o : ar)
{
  System.out.println(o.getCountry() + "\t" + o.getValue())
}
```